# xdg-mime doesn't respect $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list

Tags: archlinux, xdgutils

It all started with Visual Studio Code crashing when I tried to open the file. After troubleshooting it seems I pinned it down to an issue with MIME. Now running against the behavior I can't wrap my head around.

Basically my handlers for images stopped working. I can create a new handler for using `xdg-mime`, but when I query it or try to use opener it fails to pick the right handler.

According to manual the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list` is supposed to take precedence. The file has the right format. And xdg-mime seems to write to it, but can't query it for some reason.

1. Adding new handler

```
~ main• ❱ env XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime default feh.desktop image/jpeg
make_default_kde: No kde runtime detected
make_default_generic feh.desktop image/jpeg
Updating /home/om/.config/mimeapps.list
```

2. Checking it was added

```
~ main• ❱ cat $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list | grep image/jpeg
image/jpeg=feh.desktop
```

3. `xdg-mime query` doesn't see it, although it checks the right file first

```
~ main• ❱ env XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default image/jpeg
Checking /home/om/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /home/om/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
Checking /home/om/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
Checking /home/om/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and /home/om/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/om/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and /home/om/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/om/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and /home/om/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/om/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and /home/om/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem was with environment variables. I realized that the `/home/om/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` was overriding the `/home/om/.config/mimeapps.list`.

After I symlinked `defaults.list` to `mimeapps.list` it solved the problem, but that seemed a bit hacky.

Later I discovered that I had `XDG_DATA_DIRS` mixed with `XDG_DATA_HOME`, i.e.: `XDG_DATA_DIRS=$HOME/.local/share`, which I suspect was confusing the system-wide mime list with user-specific. After I unset the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` and set `XDG_DATA_HOME` to `$HOME/.local/share` the `xdg-mime` no longer looks for other files:

```
~ main• ❱ env XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default image/jpeg
Checking /home/om/.config/mimeapps.list
feh.desktop
```

Ref: [basedir-spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)